# CKDatabaseSubscription fails successfully when using alertLocalizationArgs and/or desiredKeys

Tags: swift, core-data, push-notification, cloudkit, cloudkit-sharing

I'm using Core Data + CloudKit && CloudKit Sharing. I'm trying to present a dynamic notification to all participants of a `CKShare` whenever any participant posts a change to the share.

I'm trying to use a `CKDatabaseSubscription` with `CKSubscription.NotificationInfo` of  `.alertLocalizationArgs` and `.desiredKeys` to get the wanted information from CloudKit. However, when adding either or both of these parameters, The subscription is not saved to my Shared Database Subscriptions in CloudKit Dashboard. - Resulting in no notification.

But if you remove `.alertLocalizationArgs` and `.desiredKeys`, the subscription will show in CloudKit Dashboard. - Resulting in a notification being displayed from the `.alertLocalizationKey`.

**The Subscription:**

```
func subscribeToSharedDBForRecordType() {

    let subscriptionID = "mySubscriptionID"
    let subscription = CKDatabaseSubscription(subscriptionID: subscriptionID)

    let recordType = "CD_MyRecordType"
    subscription.recordType = recordType

    let notificationInfo = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()

    notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = "Localized String Key" // Value: "Localized String Key" = "Test: %@";
    notificationInfo.soundName = "default"

    // --- Adding `alertLocalizationArgs` and/or `desiredKeys` casues CKDatabaseSubscription to not show up in CloudKit
    // notificationInfo.alertLocalizationArgs = ["CD_myStringArgument1"]
    // notificationInfo.desiredKeys = ["CD_myStringArgument1"]


    notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true

    subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

    let operation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: [subscription], subscriptionIDsToDelete: nil)
    operation.modifySubscriptionsResultBlock = { result in
        print(#function, "modifySubscriptionsResultBlock:")
        switch result {
            case .success(let result):
                print(".success:", result)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(".failure:", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    operation.qualityOfService = .utility

    let ckContainer: CKContainer = CKContainer(identifier: "myCKIdentifier")
    ckContainer.sharedCloudDatabase.add(operation)

    }
```

Both operations return a successful Result.

Is this the correct behavior? I'm having trouble understanding why adding .desiredKeys or .alertLocalizationArgs is causing the subscription to fail.

Note: I can't use a `CKQuerySubscription` (where the notification would fire correctly, but only for the owner) because this is on the sharedDatabase.